# Send message to facebook friends and get the recipients id's?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a web application,

In my web application I'm adding a feature to allow users to send some messages including some urls. I'm using Javascript SDK.

Is there any way to get the recepients id once the messages sent by the users please ?

I implemented the Send Button but it seems like it doesn't return any value.

Here is what I implemented : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button/

Is there any different implementation or different way to get the recepients ID once the user sent a message ?

Cheers,

Comment: may i ask what you need the IDs for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send Dialogs don´t really have any callback: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog/

You can only predefine IDs of friends with the "to" parameter, but users can change the selection in the dialog. And of course you can only use IDs of friends who authorized your App too. Without authorization, there is no way to get the ID.

TL;DR: It is not possible.